# Usage com.android.billingclient:billing and com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx library in Android Kotlin project

Tags: android, play-billing-library

On going through the Lib version for billingclient in android help [doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#dependency)

Saw that they have billing and billing-ktx lib, Do we need both to be implemented in the app or when using kotlin project can we using billing-ktx lib alone?

I have implementing both the billing and billing-ktx in the project, seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on you project. If, for instance, you need to invoke `queryPurchaseHistory` from a suspend function then you need to use `billing-ktx`.

In other words, if your project heavily relies on coroutines then `billing-ktx` will help you a lot. Also, when including `billin-ktx`, there is no need to include the standard `billing` library because it will be automatically added in the list of dependencies (you can double check it by yourself in Android Studio: from `Project` panel, expand `External Libraries`).

If that's not the case, then the standard billing library is ok.

Comment: Yes i am using suspend functions. if I include billing-ktx, is their no need to include billing lib?